# why memory usage is different whn I just change code position?

Tags: memory, pthreads

malloc at Line A will consume more memory than Line B,
why?is it relevant to pthread?

```
int main()
{
    char *buf = (char*)malloc(1024*1024*1024); //Line A
    memset(buf,0,sizeof(1024*1024*1024));
    pthread_t m_sockThreadHandle[8];
    for (int i=0;i<8;i++)
    {
      if ( pthread_create(&m_sockThreadHandle[i], NULL, thread_run, NULL) != 0 )
      {
        perror("pthread_create");
      }
    }
    sleep(10);
    char *buf = (char*)malloc(1024*1024*1024);//Line B
    memset(buf,0,sizeof(1024*1024*1024));
    for (int i=0;i<8;i++)
    {
      pthread_join(m_sockThreadHandle[i],NULL);
    }
}
```

Comment: And how are you determining that?

Answer (score 0):

Possibly because this isn't doing what you thought it was:

```
memset(buf,0,sizeof(1024*1024*1024));
```

`sizeof(1024*1024*1024)` is 4 on my compiler. I think you meant:

```
memset(buf,0, 1024*1024*1024);
```

From the code you post `buf` is unused, so it's not clear what you're trying to do, or why. But this at least is wrong....